# Matrix Exponential using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential, cayley-hamilton

For the matrix $$P=\left( \begin{matrix} 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0 \end{matrix} \right)$$ how do you find $e^{Pt}$ using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

I have found it by diagonalising $P$, but the question states to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: You don't need to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, you just need some annihilating polynomial to of the matrix to rewrite the power series. Since you are going to need the monomials $I,P,P^2$ anyway, computing the minimal polynomial directly can actually save you the (admittedly not very hard) work of computing the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 10):

If you calculate the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x)=x^3-x$, you know from Cayley-Hamilton theorem that $P^3-P=0$, i.e. $P^3=P$.

This implies that $P=P^3=P^5=\dots$ and $P^2=P^4=P^6=\dots$. Hence
$$
\begin{align}
e^{Pt} 
&= I+Pt + \frac{P^2t^2}2 + \frac{P^3t^3}{3!} + \dots = \\
&= I + P\left(t+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}+\dots\right) + P^2\left(\frac{t^2}2+\frac{t^4}{4!}+\frac{t^6}{6!}+\dots\right) = \\
&= I+ P \frac{e^t-e^{-t}}2 + P^2 \left(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}2-1\right) = \\
&= I+ P\sinh t + P^2(\cosh t-1)
\end{align}
$$

Using
$P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$
and
$P^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$
I get
$$e^{Pt}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&\sinh t&\cosh t-1\\
0&\cosh t&\sinh t\\
0&\sinh t&\cosh t
\end{pmatrix}.$$

If I did not miss something, this seems to be the same result as [WolframAlpha returns](http://tinyurl.com/qx5w52m). (Up to some algebraic manipulation.)

Comment: Thank you for your help! how did you get from the line P(t+t^3/3!+t^5/5!+.... to the following line?

Comment: It is more or less standard trick: In one of the expressions I want to get rid of all terms in Taylor series of $e^x$ with odd exponent, in another one I want to cancel out the terms with even exponents. (Or you may simply notice that they are Taylor series of [hyperbolic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function), if you remember those. They are very similar to Taylor series for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, but there are different signs.)

Comment: Nice answer!!$\;$