# Matrix power of $e$ with complex e-values

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, jordan-normal-form

> Calculate $e^A$ where $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&3\\-1&2&0\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

I knew how to do it if it was diagonalizable and real eigenvalues. How can I calculate when the matrix has complex eigenvalues. This matrix $A$ seems to have two conjugate complex evalues.

I know how to calculate $\det \left(e^A\right)$ without knowing $e^A$ as:
$$\det \left(e^A\right) = \det \left(e^J\right) = \det \left(e^{\text{tr}J}\right) = \det \left(e^{\text{tr}A}\right) = e^2$$
where $A = CJC^{-1}$ a Jordan form of $A$, but I want to calculate $e^A$.

When I tried to find its eigenvalues to diagonalize it I came to
$$\lambda^3-2\lambda^2-\lambda+5 = 0$$
which I couldn't solve.

> Also, I would really appreciate some beginner-friendly source references to learn more about problems of this type.

Comment: This is missing a little information, can you define what you mean by the matrices $C$ and $J$?

Comment: @fundamentalform $J$ is a Jordan block matrix with eigenvalues of $A$ through its diagonal.

Comment: You can compute the matrix exponential using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/724647.

Comment: @MartinR But wouldn't my characteristic polynomial be inefficient for this purpose?

Comment: You ask "How can I calculate when the matrix has complex eigenvalues?"
Completely analogous to the real-eigenvalues case!
$A$ has one real root at approx. $-1.4$ and a pair of complex-conjugate zeros. Diagonalise $A=TDT^{-1}$ & proceed to determine  $e^A=Te^DT^{-1}$.

Comment: Well, read eigenvalue of $A$, instead of root or zeros.

Comment: @Hanno But it was in my exam, so I could not find the eigenvalues. After the exam, I input it into calculator that gave one real and two complex e-values. Also, when the eigenvalues are complex, would not it change the form of $D$. I guess there would $\sin$ and $\cos$ elements in it? I don't have any good source for this stuff unfortunately.

Comment: @Moo Theoretically, I guess yes, but with this particular example I'm not.

Comment: @Moo I would so much appreciate if you could post an answer outlining all the possible cases if you have chance, please. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1535731/81360) is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the instructor had in mind for an exam approach, but there are many ways to calculate the matrix exponential, for example [*Nineteen Dubious Ways to Compute the Exponential of a Matrix, Twenty-Five Years Later*](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cvResearchPDF/19ways+.pdf).

The closed form eigenvalues / eigenvectors are quite ugly, so we will use numerical values. Because this matrix has three distinct eigenvalues, a typical approach for finding the matrix exponential is using diagonalization.

We have ($P$ are the eigenvector column vectors and $D$ are the corresponding eigenvalues)

$$e^A = P e^ D P^{-1}$$

For the matrix $A$, we have eigenvalues

$$\lambda_{1,2,3} = 1.68721 + 0.889497 i,1.68721  - 0.889497 i,-1.37442$$

The eigenvectors are

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
 1.63173\, -2.11204 i & 2.68721\, +0.889497 i & 1. \\
 1.63173\, +2.11204 i & 2.68721\, -0.889497 i & 1. \\
 -1.26346 & -0.374424 & 1. \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The exponential is given as $e^A = P e^D P^{-1}$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1.63173\, -2.11204 i & 2.68721\, +0.889497 i & 1. \\
 1.63173\, +2.11204 i & 2.68721\, -0.889497 i & 1. \\
 -1.26346 & -0.374424 & 1. \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
 e^{1.68721\, -0.889497 i} & 0. & 0. \\
 0. & e^{1.68721\, +0.889497 i} & 0. \\
 0. & 0. & \frac{1}{e^{1.37442}} \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
 0.0491893\, -0.169309 i & 0.116796\, +0.160105 i & 0.10588\, -0.153969 i \\
 0.0491893\, +0.169309 i & 0.116796\, -0.160105 i & 0.10588\, +0.153969 i \\
 -0.0983786 & -0.233592 & 0.78824 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

Multiplying these out

$$e^A = \begin{pmatrix}
 1.56484 & 3.33455 & 2.90601 \\
 -4.30322 & 5.86806 & -3.33455 \\
 -1.11152 & 2.08019 & -0.372504 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Let's compare this with [*Wolfram Alpha's*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp+%7B%7B1%2C+0%2C+3%7D%2C+%7B-1%2C+2%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+1%2C+-1%7D%7D%2F%2FN) result.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the teacher intended it to be "Find $\det e^A$" as I have shown.

Comment: Sorry for a late little comment: It will always become real after the multiplication with eigenvector matrix, won't it?

Comment: If you start out with a complex matrix, that is not the case, but for real matrices, yes.

Comment: Thank you, I got you.