# Hints or formulas to calculate $e^A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

> I am posting this question to learn calculating the matrix power $e^A$ where $A$ is a given matrix in a more **beginner-friendly** explanation. Definition of this expression is given as
> $$e^A = I + A + \frac{A^2}{2!} + \frac{A^3}{3!} + \dots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}$$

**What I know:**

1. If $A$ has **$3$ distinct eigenvalues** then, we can diagonalize it in the form $A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$ where $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\{\lambda_i: i = 1,2,\dots, n\})$. After this $$e^A = Pe^\Lambda P^{-1}$$
   where $e^\Lambda$ is just all elements of $\Lambda$ are exponentiated.
2. If $A$ has a "nice" characteristic polynomial and of smaller size then we can benefit from the Cayley Hamilton theorem as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724647/matrix-exponential-using-the-cayley-hamilton-theorem).

**Main question:**

1. What to do when the matrix $A$ has $2$ or more same eigenvalues?
2. What if there are complex eigenvalues? (this one has been more or less discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168716/matrix-power-of-e-with-complex-e-values))

> Showing some examples with $3\times 3$ matrices would be greatly appreciated i.e. two cases
>
> 1. With two same eigenvalues
> 2. With three same eigenvalues

Basic explanations are enough like "If so, use this formula, else this formula", I will try to do the rest of the deeper learning myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Putzer Algorithm or use the Jordan normal form

Comment: Exponential of Jordan blocks is discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204380/the-exponential-of-a-jordan-block

Comment: Look this post: [Matrix exponential for Jordan canonical form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451276/matrix-exponential-for-jordan-canonical-form)

Comment: Why should the number 3 of eigenvalues play a special role here?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I just wanted to see with examples of $3\times 3$ matrices.